# Customizing UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

In the Twitterific app, there's a control that looks like UIActionSheet but it looks customized.

I would like to know how to make a view that similar look & feel with the buttons in a horizontal row instead of the default vertical. Any one have any suggestions to a link for a tutorial or sample code to get started on this?

[alt text http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/8784/twitterific.th.jpg](http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/8784/twitterific.th.jpg)

The standard [ActionSheet as shown by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW1).

Answer (score 3):

That's just a normal UIView subclass which draws the gradient background using Core Graphics (I don't expect it to be an image) and has some UIButtons as subviews (Either staticly positioned and added to the view or all being positioned by code. Doing it staticly will make things easier but less reusable)

Answer (score 2):

I'm virtually certain this a custom UIView.

It's really not all that complicated - most of the work is the nice looking button images.

You'd create a view with appropriately positioned UIButtons, then simply slide it into place at the appropriate time.